# Bootstrap modal form is so ugly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need help i cant figure out why my modal login form is not conforming to any changes and doesn't look like the standard bootstrap form.

nav.php

```
<!-- Modal HTML -->
     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                 </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Please log in below</p>
                    <form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <label class="label" for="user" style="color: black">Username</label></br>
                            <input id="user" type="text" name="user" size="30" class="input-large" placeholder="username" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <label class="label" for="pass"style="color: black">Password</label></br>
                            <input id="pass" type="text" name="pass" size="30" class="input-large" placeholder="Password"required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label> <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />

                    <input class="btn btn-success" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 6px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
              </form>
                 </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**here is what it looks like** 
[image]

**here is an example of what i want it to look like**
[image]

Comment: change input class `class="input-large"` to `class="form-control"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) is your friend. Forms, inputs, and their labels need `form-group` and `form-control` (among other classes) attached to them.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: People using bootstrap and not using class 'form-control' . What is going on ?